# Would you prefer to use String\NSString or Array/NSArray and etc in swift

Tags: class, swift, structure

Would you prefer to use String\NSString or Array/NSArray and etc in swift

or what depends on to choose?

Answer (score 3):

`String` and `Array` are <s>supercharged</s> enhanced versions of `NSString` `NSArray`. `String` has better UTF support, `Array` uses generics and more. `NSString` and `NSArray` should be used only when necessary, such as when using objective-c code from swift or accessing iOS/MacOS APIs

However each pair is interchangeable and (almost) automatically bridged when needed, so you can pass an `Array` where a `NSArray` is required, and vice versa. Same applies to strings.

Comment: While I agree with all the recommendations, it's somewhat misleading to say that `String` and `Array` are supercharged versions of their `NS` equivalents. The `NS` versions have many methods not available on their Swift counterparts. You should still generally use the Swift version; no argument there. But mostly for type safety, not for their feature-set.

Comment: I agree but also disagree :) A lot of `NSString` methods are not available in `String`, some of them very useful, and I often wondered why. However I agree that _supercharged_ is exaggerate - replacing it with *enhanced*, it's more appropriate

Comment: As Antonio mentioned, important methods are available to NSString but not String such as .floatVlaue and .doubleValue for conversions.